# Is it normal for my Mac to have 60GB in .MobileBackups? I use Time Machine

Tags: osx-lion

I have a 256GB SSD (and a fat 1TB HDD as well) in my Lion-running MacBook Pro.

I use an external drive for Time Machine and have backed up recently.

So why might I have a 57.8GB .MobileBackups folder in my system root?

Is this normal, and what can I do to shrink it?

Answer (score 0):

I [found](http://wiki.summercode.com/how_to_disable_mobile_backups_on_lion) that you can disable this feature, which [supposedly](http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2011/07/mac-os-x-10-7.ars/18) is a buffer between your computer and your Time Machine when on the road (and thus logically shouldn't be that big for me...):

```
sudo tmutil disablelocal
```

then reboot.

Comment: The local Time Machine backups use part of the available space you have on your laptop drive (it's only configured for mobile devices).  If your available space gets smaller, less local backups are kept, if it grows bigger, the opposite.